# Do I need to pay for Heroku Postgre Followers and/or Forks?

Tags: heroku

I just moved my database to the Heroku Postgre Crane production plan and I want to create forks and followers. My question is, are these free features or do I to need pay for the fork and follower databases?

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this so any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: Well I just tried to do it from their postgres.heroku.com site and it seems that it is not free. My follow question is, is this new database prorated by the hour just like dynos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pay for all the databases that you create, but note that they don't all have to be on the same plan. Like dynos, costs are prorated per second that you have the database added. Details here: https://postgres.heroku.com/pricing

Comment: Thanks! Too bad they dont mention that forks and followers have to be paid for on their pricing page or anywhere on their docs.

Comment: It's mentioned in the documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-follower-databases "Followers are only supported on production tier database plans. "